# How to get a string[] as value from a Dictionary<int, string[]> regroup all value

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dictionary, enumerable

I have a `Dictionary<int, string[]>`.
And I want to know, if with the functions of Enumerable/Collection it's possible to get in one line "approximatly", to regroup all `string[]` value in one array string ?

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> dicoMailPerPage = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
dicoMailPerPage.Add(pageX, objetLanda.Select(t => t.mail).ToArray());
...
string[] allMail = dicoMailPerPage.Values.Something... // My problem
```

Thanks

I had to look for zip/aggregate... but it's not want i need, i think.

Comment: What programming language is this? Please specify this into a tags.

Comment: And if my assumption is correct and this is C#, then look at the `IEnumerable.SelectMany` LINQ extension method - `dicoMailPerPage.Values.SelectMany(x=>x);`

Comment: Yes i  just see that there a few minutes i'll try with SelectMany thanks.